# How to call sadf, so it automatically detects latest sar statistics?

Tags: sar, sysstat

I'm looking for a way to get `sadf` (from `sysstat` package) to generate me the csv version of the collected data by `sar` of the current day.

I know that `sar` keeps it's configuration in `/etc/sysstat/sysstat` where it has it's SA_DIR specified. In my case (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) it shows:

```
SA_DIR=/var/log/sysstat
```

I would like to get this value and use it for the `sadf` command like:

```
# instead of the hard coded path...
sadf -d /var/log/sysstat/sa$(date +%d -d yesterday)
# ... I would like something like this with a SA_DIR variable
sadf -d $SA_DIR/sa$(date +%d -d today)
```

How can I get the `SA_DIR` form the `sar` configuration file?

---

With @steve 's **solution** I ended up using sadf like this:

```
# Generate CSV's
. /etc/sysstat/sysstat
sadf -d $SA_DIR/sa$(date +%d -d today) -- -r     > memory_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`.csv  # Memory statistics
sadf -d $SA_DIR/sa$(date +%d -d today) -- -n DEV > network_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`.csv # Network statistics
sadf -d $SA_DIR/sa$(date +%d -d today) -- -u     > cpu_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`.csv     # CPU statistics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `. /etc/sysstat/sysstat` within your script.  That will result in environment variable `$SA_DIR` being set appropriately.